# sqlalchemy error when attempting to execute SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm getting the error "mapping or sequence expected for parameters" in the method below. These stored procs do not have any parameters, however, I'm not even sure the sprocs in and of themselves are the issue. It may be what sqlalchemy expects in a `session.execute` statement?

```
def mssqlDataPrep():
try:
    
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + srvr + '/' + db + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server')

    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    s = Session()
         
    src_tables = s.execute("""select t.name as table_name from sys.tables t where t.name in ('UPrices') union select t.name as table_name from sys.tables t where t.name in ('ExtractViewFromPrices') """ )


    for tbl in src_tables:


        if str(tbl[0]) == 'ExtractViewFromPrices':
           populateFromSrcVwQry = f'''exec stg.PopulateExtractViewFromPrices'''
           

           exec_sproc_extract = s.execute(populateFromSrcVwQry,engine)


        else:
           populateUQry = f'''exec stg.PopulateUPrices''' 
           exec_sproc_u = s.execute(populateUQry,engine)
          
except Exception as e:
    print("Data prep error: " + str(e))
```

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: The version I am using is 1.4.41

Comment: In SQLAlchemy 1.3 or earlier you could supply a plain SQL string to [Session.execute()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute). Since 1.4, though, the first parameter to [Session.execute()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.execute) is meant to be an Executable expression object, such as a `select()` statement. Have you read the [Calling Stored Procedures and Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions) documentation?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning! I solved the issue by just using pyodbc  cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("EXEC "+src_vw_sproc)
        connection.commit()   -- but I will look into the latest version of the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

For those following this thread, @AlwaysLearning pointed me to the correct documentation for invoking a stored proc from sqlalchemy. However, I solved the problem through pyodbc with the following code:

```
upside_sproc = 'schema.my_sproc_name'
engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{pwd}@{srvr}:1433/{db}?driver={dr}")
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("EXEC "+upside_sproc)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Please note that this particular stored proc does not have parameters, nor am I looking to work with a result set. For this, please refer to @AlwaysLearning's comment under Calling Stored Procedures and Functions, as sqlalchemy is better suited for that.